# Problems with reproducibility although setting a fix set.seed() in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, reproducible-research

I'm using the package and function `lpsymphony::lpsymphony_solve_LP(obj, mat, dir, rhs, types, max)` to solve my linear programming problem.

And now I want to show that the restrictions in the argument `mat` matter and therefore I solved this problem with only a subset of restrictions - only some rows of `mat` are used to get the solution. And here the solution changes every time I reexecute.

**Questions**: Why there is no reproducibility and how can I solve this issue?!

But now let's have a look at my code:

```
# objective function
obj = rep(1, times = (196))

# other arguments
...

# first solution
set.seed(455)
res_231=lpsymphony_solve_LP(obj, mat[1:231,], dir[1:231], rhs[1:231], types = types, max = TRUE)
matrix(c(res_231$solution[29:56]),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
##  [1,]    0    0    0    0
##  [2,]    0    0    0    1
##  [3,]    0    0    0    0
##  [4,]    1    1    0    0  
##  [5,]    0    0    1    0
##  [6,]    0    0    0    0
##  [7,]    0    0    0    0


# second solution
set.seed(455)
res_231=lpsymphony_solve_LP(obj, mat[1:231,], dir[1:231], rhs[1:231], types = types, max = TRUE)
matrix(c(res_231$solution[29:56]),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
##  [1,]    0    0    0    0
##  [2,]    0    0    0    1
##  [3,]    0    0    0    0
##  [4,]    0    1    0    0
##  [5,]    1    0    0    0  # difference in [5,1] compared to first solution
##  [6,]    0    0    1    0  # difference in [6,3] compared to first solution
##  [7,]    0    0    0    0
```

And an excerpt of the session info

```
session_info()
##  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
##  ...
##  lpsymphony  * 1.20.0  2021-05-19 [1] Bioconductor (R 4.1.0)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This function seems to interface a C library. My guess is that this library uses its own RNG (or at least not an R RNG) and the interface does pass on the seed.

Comment: @Roland: And do you have any idea how I can alter the "internal" RNG?

Comment: No, sorry. You would first need to investigate if my hypothesis is correct.